# Is there a pattern to the golden ratio number figures?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pattern-recognition, golden-ratio

The golden ratio or phi is 1.6180339887498948482045... I am wondering if there is a pattern in the numbers so given a certain set of figures, you are able to figure out the rest of the figures aaccurately? Essentially is there a pattern that someone could follow and say you were given 1.6180339887 and from the pattern formulated you can figure that the next numbers are 498948...?

Comment: Do you know that $\phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Given a finite sequence of numbers, it is impossible to answer the question what is the next number of the sequence.  Such questions usually rely on there being a fairly simple recognizable pattern, but there is always an implicit assumption that the pattern will continue.  However, there is no guarantee that this is true.

Suppose that a sequence starts: $1,4,7$.  If asked for the next number of the sequence, most people would respond $10$.  However, if you pick any positive integer $n$, there is a degree 3 polynomial $P$ such that $P(1)=1, P(2)=4, P(3)=7$ and $P(4)=n$.  So your question is ill conceived.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate all of the digits of $\phi$ without having any of the previous digits by just evaluating $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. However, if you are trying to find a pattern in the digits, this is an unsolved problem. If the digits of a number are evenly distributed and every digit is just as likely as any other digit, then the number is called *normal*. Proving that a number is normal is extremely difficult unless the number was defined to have uniformly distributed digits. You can read more [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html).

Comment: How can you calculate all the digits of $\phi$ without having any of the previous digits in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The Golden ratio is well-known for being written with repeating patterns, such as :  $$\phi = 1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \ddots}}}$$
or $$\phi = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}}}\,.$$
It can be written as a series:
$$\phi=\frac{13}{8}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}(2n+1)!}{(n+2)!n!4^{(2n+3)}}\,.$$
It can be derived from the Fibonacci sequence, where [several patterns exist](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibmaths.html). Yet, I am not unware of a pattern in its digits in base $10$.